# Will Perseverance explore the outskirts of Jezero?

Tags: perseverance, crater

Perseverance landed in the Jezero crater and [has been exploring the area around its landing site](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/mission/where-is-the-rover/).

The crater use to be filled with water, so the bottom of the crater was covered with sedimentary rocks. So we can't see the kind of rock that was under the surface before the crater was created. But if we went around the crater, we could find ejecta that shows what the rocks were like under the surface.

Are there any plans for Perseverance to go explore the outer edge of the crater?